# Asking user for const

Tags: c++, constants

There is my friend's code. It works, but we would like to ask our user how many times he wants to type informations. Simplier, We don't know how to ask my user for N ("const int N = 3" line). We've tried changing "const int" into "int", but then an error shows up "expression must have a constant value".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct T_dane_ksiazki
{
    char imie[15];
    char nazwisko[30];
    char tytul[45];
    int rokwydania;
    int nrwydania;
};
void WCZYTAJ_dane(T_dane_ksiazki& dane) /*wczytanie informacji o książce*/
{
    cout << "\nimie autora: ";
    cin >> dane.imie;
    cout << "nazwisko autora: ";
    cin >> dane.nazwisko;
    cout << "tytul ksiazki: ";
    cin >> dane.tytul;
    cout << "rok wydania: ";
    cin >> dane.rokwydania;
    cout << "numer wydania: ";
    cin >> dane.nrwydania;
}
void WYSWIETL_dane(T_dane_ksiazki dane) /*wczytanie informacji o książce*/
{
    cout << "\nimie autora: " << dane.imie;
    cout << "\nnazwisko autora: " << dane.nazwisko;
    cout << "\ntytul ksiazki: " << dane.tytul;
    cout << "\nrok wydania: " << dane.rokwydania;
    cout << "\nnumer wydania: " << dane.nrwydania << "\n";
}

const int N = 3;
int Zapytajka()
{
    cout << N<< "\n";
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    T_dane_ksiazki daneq[N];
    Zapytajka();
    cout << "Podaj informacje o ksiazkach: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        WCZYTAJ_dane(daneq[i]);
    }
    cout << "\n\nInformacje o ksiazkch: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        WYSWIETL_dane(daneq[i]);

    }
    cout << "\nKoniec programu. Nacisnij ENTER";
    cin.ignore(); cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Another remark is what you see already: In this globalized world it's advisable to write your code with English identifiers. I have not worked in a team without foreigners since 2003 or so.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, you're right sir.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: To be fair, calling any non-English speaker a _foreigner_ is a bit misleading. For me any native English speaker is a foreigner!

Comment: @rodrigo: From his profile and name I strongly suspect Peter is also a non-native English speaker.

Comment: If you remove the double-negative, the idea is "there are people on your team that are not fluent in your native language - use English to communicate with them".

Comment: @rodrigo Oh, I'm German :-). Between Germans, Asian Indians, Turks, Polish, Norwegians, Ukrainians and probably others on the team (or communicating teams) the *lingua franca* is English. Some older East Germans would prefer Russian, but it's a technical environment wheere the need for true English words is limited and most technical terms are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ only supports arrays whose size is constant. However, if you want a non-constant size, you can use `vector`, which was designed specifically for this purpose.

Example:

```
#include <vector>

...

int main()
{
    Zapytajka();
    cout << "Podaj informacje o ksiazkach: \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    std::vector<T_dane_ksiazki> daneq(N); // moved here and modified
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        WCZYTAJ_dane(daneq[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

I changed an array to a `vector`, and moved its definition to after the value of `n` is determined. I also changed `N` to `n` because it's no longer a constant, and it's a common convention to allocate lower-case names to variables.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I missed that it is a C++ question. The answer for C++ is that you should use a C++ container, probably a vector. These containers are the reason that the variable length arrays introduced in C in 1999 discussed below do not exist in C++: There is no real need for them. (There is a discussion whether to introduce something like it but it has non-trivial implications for the type system.)

You can have variable length arrays in C99 programs (for gcc: compile with "-std=c99"). That is, you can make N a non-const and the program should still compile and run properly (I didn't check every detail, but it looks pretty straightforward).

In pre-99 C you have to allocate dynamically with malloc or simply define an array which is big enough for the biggest conceivable number and use only part of it.

Comment: This question is about C++, not C.

Comment: @PreferenceBean Oh, I truly missed that, in spite of the many `cin` and `cout`.